# EXCEL datetime row changed to "42507" after import into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I got a problem, I have imported this Excel sheet into SQL Server several times, before it worked fine.

But suddenly there are 2 rows (datetime) with invalid data. In Excel, the datetime row has been all changed to `2016/12/12`

But when the data is imported into SQL Server, some will change to sort of `42507` format, and couldn't calculate using datediff.

I was quite confused of this, can anyone help? Any of your idea is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as integers, the number of days since 1899-12-30, you can use `=TEXT(A1,”yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss”)` in Excel to store the text value for easy import, but if you already have the integers in SQL you can use `DATEADD(day,yourDate,'1899-12-30')` to convert it to the proper date.

.xlsx (and .docx,pptx etc) files are just archives and the meat of your documents are stored in xml files. You can change the extension to .zip and open the archive to explore how the data is actually stored, in most if not all cases, cell formatting doesn't affect the underlying values.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that field in Excel is set to date and then import the sheet.
You can also cast the 5 digit as datetime:

```
UPDATE <yourTable>
SET <dateColumn> = CAST(<dateColumn> as datetime)
WHERE LEN(<dateColumn>) = 5
```

Comment: This will give you the wrong date as day zero is not consistent between Excel and SQL Server.